# Ad banner is not display in UIStoryboard application in Xcode 4.5

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios6, admob, xcode4.5

I have create tab based application using Xcode 4.5.
I have also use ARC and storyboard in this application.

Now, In one view controller, I have add Ad banner using following code. But that is not display.

```
 CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
banner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];
banner.adUnitID =  @"a150b2168c416af" ;//@"2d4ff087826f4ba5";
banner.delegate = self;
banner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:banner];
[banner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

So, How to display Ad in this application?
and how to manage this ad view on both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 screens?

I have use AdMob SDK in this application.

Comment: Is the ad request still returning correctly, so is your adViewDidReceiveAd: callback getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your banner got below the view? Try this to force it on top:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:banner]
```